# R CMD check pkg --offline

Tags: r

Any way to prevent check process trying to connect to network?
Something like `--offline` argument to `R CMD check`.

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ...Warning: unable to access index for repository http://CRAN.R-project.org/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/bioc/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/data/annotation/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.1/data/experiment/src/contrib
Warning in url(sprintf("%s/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz", u), "rb") :
  unable to resolve 'CRAN.R-project.org'
NB: need Internet access to use CRAN incoming checks
```

`R CMD check --help` does not list such feature.

Comment: this froze my check pipeline when the bioconductor mirror stopped responding. There should be a way to check a package offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the recent R version 3.4.0 it is possible as described in [NEWS](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html) file:

> Running R CMD check --as-cran with _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_ false now skips tests that require remote access. The remaining (local) tests typically run quickly compared to the remote tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `--as-cran` option, since checking the CRAN incoming feasibility only happens when that option is turned on.

Otherwise there is no way to disable it, since the CRAN check requires verifying the existing CRAN status with respect to some things with packages or your package.  See the section *Checking CRAN incoming feasibility* in http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html for details.

Comment: maybe there is a way to do it offline? for example `git clone https://github.com/eddelbuettel/crp` / `pull` and just point that dir during `check`?

Comment: The crp repo is not parseable and not use by your standard `R CMD check` call.